# Angular Folder Structure

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I'm confused with the correct structure of my angular application. May i ask for advice for the correct Angular structure of my app? What is the correct structure according to the Angular docs? I'm confused. Thanks. Please see the 2 Angular structure on my image. Do i need to separate the services and models to a different folder?

[image: Structure 1][image: Structure 2]

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Yes i been through it. I just need some help. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular folder structure and component services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779093/angular-folder-structure-and-component-services)

Comment: Then what is unclear from it? Opinion-based questions like this are not a good fit from SO; it's up to you and your team to decide what's best for you.

Comment: Like @jonrsharpe mentioned there is a styleguide. Which shows one way of doing it . The most important thing about folder structure is being consistent and making sure your whole team does it the same.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. I mean i just need clarification on whether to put services and models on a separate folder?

Comment: It's up to you. If you want to know how the Angular team would recommend doing it, look at the example layout which answers that question.

Comment: @Jelle. Please don't vote the close. I really need help/advise from other developers too. Thank you

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Please don't vote the close. I really need help/advise from other developers too. Thank you

Comment: As above, SO doesn't offer advice on opinion-based matters. If that's what you want, you should seek it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No specific folder structure is "correct". If your application is small and you just have a few components and a single module, I would keep it simple in a flat structure. If there are lot's of modules and components, maybe group components and services in the same folder as the module where they are declared.

In any case the folder structure is not what makes your Angular app work or not, but you should make it in a way that navigating your source files is as easy and readable as possible.

Also see this: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#flat

Comment: Which do you prefer? the first or the second image?

Comment: I prefer the first (the one to the left).

Comment: Ok. services and models are NOT made to a different folder?

Comment: Yes - I prefer to have everything concerning users (including model and services) in the users folder, and branches in the branches folder.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer :)